# SELECT with amount of all rows of associated table and join this rows. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL:

**Table A**

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| ... |
| 100 |

**Table B**

| id | boolean | table_a_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 5300 | 1 | 100 |

Table.A has many Table.B.

So i want to SELECT 3 rows from Table.A with additional field in which amount of all associated B rows is calculated, but SELECT from A only which have 100 or more rows in B (ORDER by total_b_rows DESC LIMIT 3) and also all associated rows in B should have at least 85% of true value in boolean column. And amount of joined B rows should be 5.

**Result**

| id | total_b_rows | table_b.id | table_b.boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | 1 |

**Total rows: 15**

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the thresholds and then order and limit to 15 rows (that ensures there are exactly 3 table a ids):

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             count(*) over (partition by table_a_id) as cnt,
             avg(boolean) over (partition by table_a_id) as ratio,
             row_number() over (partition by table_a_id order by table_a_id) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
where cnt > 100 and ratio > 0.85 and seqnum <= 5
order by table_a_id
limit 15
```

Comment: Thank you man! Going to learn more about nested queries and window functions